# Can I determine if my Electro magnetic field (EMF) measuring device is in very close proximity to the source of EMF?

Tags: emf

I am trying to solve a problem of identifying programmatically if I (or my measuring device) is in very close proximity to an EMF source.

The situation is, I have an EMF emitting source (sorry if I got the terminology wrong, I am not a physics student) and I also have a device which can measure the EMF in milli Gaus.
The device gives the value of EMF in x, y and z direction and also the total EMF (don't know how it gets this value).

Based on this setting, I am trying to figure out if I can find if my measuring device is in close proximity of the EMF source. By proximity, I mean lower than some preset distance from the source. So a distance measure would be useful. My questions are

1. Is there a way to know if I am close to the source by getting a measure of the EMF values from my measuring device?
2. Given that there is lot of interference, what is the best way to tag a set of EMF values for the source so that I can detect when I can (programmatically) determine if I am in close proximity of the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are asking is "How can I improve my emitter so I can detect it unambiguously in the presence of background noise or interference"?

Ok, so your detector is a magnetic flux density measuring device hence it produces an output in gauss (these days magnetic flux density is measured in teslas or webers per sq metre). I am also presuming your source is something that is either a permanent magnet or something like a coil of wire excited with an AC signal.

If it's a permanent magnet I can't help you but if it is a coil of wire and it is producing an alternating magnetic field then it is detectable by using another coil and measuring the induced voltage. To avoid interference you can resonant tune the receiver coil to be mainly responsive to the frequency produced by the emitter. I don't think your sensor will help you in this respect - I'd use a coil of wire - It all depends what is more important to you; using your sensor or getting good results by a better technique.

So if you have a "send" coil and a "receive" coil, the basic maths is like this: -

[image]

Looking at the transmitter, if the distance from the loop/coil is small (Z a lot less than R) the flux density (B) is nearly constant but, as distance increases B reduces as the cube-root of Z.

On the receiver side, and assuming the received flux is constant across its area (not really too much of an approximation beyond certain distances), the induced voltage is proportional to the area of the loop, the peak flux density and the frequency of excitation.

Basic conclusion - up close the flux density can be almost constant and hence the induced voltage won't change too much but, further away you can use the induced voltage level to determine the distance.

Comment: I have the choice of selecting the source.That is, I am using an EMF source to tag a point or another device, if that makes sense. But on the receiver side, what I have is only a digital measuring device which gives the value of flux in mG which I assume to be Bz. So, I am thinking... use the Bz formula and get the z from it as all other values are known.

Comment: Is the source an alternating magnetic field or just constant like a permanent magnet?

Comment: I can choose the source. My source could be an alternating magnetic field generator provided it is very small(The size of a computer mouse) and very cheap. Again, I am not sure if it's possible to get such a source and the feasibility of getting such a source will determine my direction of study to a great extent...

Comment: What frequency range does your receiver have? For instance, generating a magnetic field at several kHz or above is optimum because it gets you away from AC magnetic fields. Being able to apply filtering to your received signal is also a good idea so you can tailor the sensitivity to the transmitter. What sort of distance are you looking for? A source the size of a mouse is no problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, the frequency range of my measuring device might be between 25Hz-50Hz. What I am using for measuring is [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.superphunlabs.emf) and this is pretty much fixed.

Comment: Well, according to this link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.superphunlabs.emf one guy says it's good up to 10kHz but the problem is really you have no way to filter out noise.

Comment: May be when I am close by this oscillating source, my device would sample the signal and would note spikes and falls in the Bz at frequencies that are unique to the source. Also, I will have a preset range of values for the amplitude of the spikes are going to be as I know the source... thus determining that I am close to the source which is the problem I am trying to solve....

Answer (score 1):

You can't determine distance from any single measurement — a certain reading could come from a weak source nearby or a stronger source farther away.

But if you take measurements at four or more different positions (not all in the same line or plane), and knowing that the field strength obeys an inverse-square law, you can set up a system of equations that you can solve to determine direction and distance. You can also take advantage of the fact that each EMF measurement is a vector quantity, and estimate the curvature of the field (change in direction at different positions), which offers addtional clues about direction and distance.

Of course, interference will add random offsets to the readings that will make it difficult to obtain an unambiguous result. To the extent that you can create a detector that is selective for a particular source (e.g., from knowing its particular frequency or harmonic content), you can improve the quality of the raw readings for that source.